# Which datetype and "set type" to use when storing numbers from spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, sql, google-apps-script, prepared-statement

I'm trying to read values from a spreadsheet using Google Apps Script and write them to Google Cloud SQL using a prepared statement, but I'm getting all kinds of problems when trying to store numbers, specifically price values. I've tried using the FLOAT and NUMERIC(15,2) datatypes for the column in the database, and the setFloat, setObject and setBigDecimal methods for setting the parameters. I'm getting a bunch of different errors like "out of range" and "incorrect decimal value"?

The number I'm trying to store appears to be a Javascript Number object, so do I need to do something to cast it to a datatype that the "set" method and/or the database recognize? Generally speaking, I'm having tons of problems related to converting datatypes in SQL. Are there any good tutorials out there for debugging this kind of issue?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. With a DECIMAL datatype, I can use either setFloat or setDouble.